# How to correctly create C++ object file (.o) on OS X?

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I'm a Java developer with very little native coding experience and I want to create my first Java-Native-Interface demo. I'm trying to do so using Kotlin and C++ in the same way as [this example](https://github.com/fuzzdota/kotlin-jni-example). I'm developing on OS X.

I am stuck at the step where I am supposed to compile a dynamic library (.so file) from my c++ files.

The 2 files in my `jni/` folder to start are:

- matt_extend_NativeTest.h
- matt_extend_NativeTestImp.cpp

The steps I'm trying to take to build the .so file are:

**1.**`g++ -g jni/matt_extend_NativeTest.h -I "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.jdk/Contents/Home/include" -I "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.jdk/Contents/Home/include/darwin" -o jni/matt_extend_NativeTest.o`

- This generates **matt_extend_NativeTest.o**

**2.**`g++ -g -I "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.jdk/Contents/Home/include" -I "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.jdk/Contents/Home/include/linux" -shared -o jni/libnativetest.so jni/matt_extend_NativeTest.o`

- This generates **libnativetest.so** but I get a warning:

`ld: warning: ignoring file jni/matt_extend_NativeTest.o, file was built for unsupported file format ( 0x43 0x50 0x43 0x48 0x01 0x08 0x00 0x00 0xAE 0x0A 0x00 0x00 0x07 0xC1 0xB3 0xD0 ) which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): jni/matt_extend_NativeTest.o`

What is the correct way to generate the .o file in step 1 so that I don't get the warning in step 2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first command has two errors:

1. instead of `jni/matt_extend_NativeTest.h`, use `jni/matt_extend_NativeTestImp.cpp`, as we compile the `.cpp` file, not the `.h`
2. use an additional `-c` flag to the compiler, so it generates an object file (instead of an executable)

Note: you maybe need to use the `-fpic` option as well (to generate position independent code).

(With the current wrong options, g++ generates a precompiled header file instead of an object file)